# C++ what are std::shared_future and std::promise

Tags: c++, c++11, future

I understand what's std::future but i don't understand when and HOW to use  std::shared_future and std::promise, and i couldn't find a good explanation online.

I will appreciate some help wrapping my head around it.

By the way the example here isn't really clear http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future

Comment: Recommendations to find a tutorial or an external explanation are off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: what about  helpful example?

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I don't see any request for external resources in this question. I see a statement that OP was not about to find an external resource, but he isn't asking us to provide one.

Comment: *"The class template std::shared_future provides a mechanism to access the result of asynchronous operations, similar to std::future, except that multiple threads are allowed to wait for the same shared state. Unlike std::future, which is only moveable (so only one instance can refer to any particular asynchronous result), std::shared_future is copyable and multiple shared future objects may refer to the same shared state."*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`std::shared_future` is when you need to have multiple valid copies of a `std::future`, and possibly multiple *consumers* of said `std::future`.

You can move a `std::future` into a `std::shared_future`.

Consider `std::future`:`std::shared_future` to be like `std::unique_ptr`:`std::shared_ptr`.

---

`std::promise` is one way to generate a `std::future`.

```
template<class T>
std::future<std::decay_t<T>> make_ready_future( T&& t ) {
  std::promise<std::decay_t<T>> pr;
  auto r = pr.get_future();
  pr.set_value(std::forward<T>(t));
  return r;
}
```

this is a toy example of `std::promise`, where I take a `T` and I generate an already-ready `std::future<T>` from it.

If you have code that could require threading off, or might already be calculated, you can return a `std::future<T>` from it.  If it isn't calculated, you return the result of a `std::async( ... )` call.  If it is already calculated, you return a `make_ready_future( calculated value )`.

A slightly more complex situation:

```
template<class T>
struct promise_pipe {
  std::future<T> out;
  std::function<void(T)> in;
  promise_pipe() {
    auto pr = std::make_shared<std::promise<T>>();
    out = pr->get_future();
    in = [pr](T t)mutable{
      if (pr) pr->set_value(std::forward<T>(t));
      pr = {};
    };
  }
};
```

Here I have written a `promise_pipe`.

A `promise_pipe<int>` has two fields -- a `std::future<int> out` and a `std::function<void(int)> in`.

The `out` future will be ready if and only if you call `in` with an `int`.

So you can have a function that returns a `std::future<Bitmap>`.  You have some network code that is expecting the bitmap to be streamed.  So you create a `promise_pipe<Bitmap>`, return the `std::future<Bitmap>` and store the `in` in a "todo" list when the bitmap arrives.

When the bitmap has fully arrived, you just do `in(Bitmap)` and whomever is waiting on that `future` will be notified.

---

`promise`s are objects designed to allow programmers to generate their own `future`s, not just use ones created by the `std` library.

Now a `packaged_task` is often easier to work with than a `std::promise`, and serves much the same purpose as the `promise_pipe` above.  It is move-only, so you can end up having to wrap it into a `std::shared_ptr` and a `std::function` anyhow (or a custom move-only `std::function`)